# How to configure bucket name during building query to couchbase via gocb

Tags: go, couchbase, gocb, go-couchbase

I need to select all agents from couchbase bucket. I am using https://github.com/couchbase/gocb package to work with couchbase.

My current query looks like:

```golang
SELECT  a.* FROM `agents` a WHERE a.type=$1
```

But I feel I need to replace bucket name with some placeholder, or parameter that will be set before sending query to couchbase.

Can anyone tell me how to do that (without `Sprintf` :) )?

---

### *UPD*

For now I am using this helper function:

```golang
import (
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/couchbase/gocb.v1"
)

const bucketPlaceholder = "{{bucket}}"

func PrepareQuery(b *gocb.Bucket, q string) string {
    return strings.ReplaceAll(q, bucketPlaceholder, b.Name())
}
```

Comment: I'm not a go dev, but: if you are trying to parameterize the bucket name (like you're doing with type=$1), then that's not (currently) possible. You *can* get the bucket name from the bucket object and use that in the query string (I assume that's what you mean by Sprintf)

Comment: Yes, is that what I meant.

Comment: I guess you have a problem of concept here. A bucket is NOT something similar to a table in a RDBMS, a bucket is similar to a Schema. So in theory you would never select all documents of your bucket because this is similar to select all rows of your whole database.

Comment: Your updated code makes sense to me: you're using the Name() from the bucket object, so in case the bucket name changes at some point, your queries will still work. However, I'm not sure about using a placeholder. Again, I'm not a go dev, but is there a way to do this with string interpolation instead?

Comment: @MatthewGroves, Yes, we can use string interpolation via formatting string like `fmt.Sprintf("SELECT a.* FROM %s a", b.Name())`